# How to update JSONB column postgres JDBC?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jdbc, sql-update

I have a JSONB column in my postgres table, I want to update the some fields in that column using JDBC.

Please help to for a JDBC query to update JSONB column.

Comment: There is no JDBC query - you use SQL queries with JDBC. You have to provide more details for an answer.

Comment: Show what you tried, and explain why that isn't working for you.

Comment: I have below given jsonb in my table,
"App": {
  "app_name": "crunc",
  "accountname": "Hanumaraddy",
  "marketplace": "US",
  "account_type": "test"
 }

Account_type and marketplace field has to update in regular intervals. I'm looking for a query to update it. Please help me on this.

Comment: Just run an `UPDATE` statement through JDBC

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess you would need to first connect by creating the object 'conn' in your code base with something of the like, more details on this step [here](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0002/).

// create a Statement from the connection
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

and then embed the SQL query in the JDBC as usual in Java yes.

2. And write the appropiate query, this should work for example in order to leave null all entries with marketplace equal to US:

// update the data
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE mytable SET App = jsonb_set(App, '{marketplace}', '""') where data ->>'marketplace' = 'US' ");